# std::set that has multiple sorting options

Tags: c++

I would like to have **multiple sorting options** for a c++ std::set container.
I tried to create a custom comparator that refers to a private class member (sortingMethod) in order to decide how to sort:

```
class StudentBook{
    int sortingMethod; //0-BY_ID, 1-BY_AGE, 2-BY_GPA, etc...
    struct studentComparator {
        bool operator()(Student* a, Student* b)
        {
            switch (sortingMethod) {
            case 1:
                return a->getId() >= b->getId();
                break;
            case 2:
                return a->getAge() >= b->getAge();
                break;
            case 3:
                return a->getGPA() >= b->getGPA();
                break;
            default:
                return true;
                break;
        }
    };
    std::set<Student*, studentComparator> students;
```

}

This code does not compile. Errors:

> "from this location", "invalid use of non-static data member 'StudentBook::sortingMethod'"

I want to use a set because of its no-duplicates property.
Is there a correct way to do it, or should I switch to another STL container?

Comment: Switching the sorting mode would need to cause a full restructuring of the `std::set`. I doubt whether there's a way to do it. You could just have a wrapper around the real structure (for each comparator) that holds a reference to an actual instance of the data and has a proper comparison operator for a given use case.

Comment: a) A struct inside a class is independent of it. You can't access `sortingMethod` in `studentComparator`  if `sortingMethod` is a part of `StudentBook`, you need some object of `StudentBook` for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in you code is that you try to refer to `sortingMethod` inside the `studentComparator` class. You cannot do that, since `studentComparator` is a standalone class, and cannot access a member variable of the enclosing class unless you pass a pointer/reference of the outer instance to the inner instance (I think this is one of the (many) differences between C++ and Java). Encapsulate the `sortingMethod` inside `studentComparator` and pass it via its constructor.

The idea is to construct a comparator functor that takes as a constructor parameter the way you want to sort. In other words, your comparator functor has *state*. When construct the `std::set` you need to explicitly [pass the comparator to its constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set). 
Below is a simple example of how to do it, with a 2-state boolean comparator, which you can further generalize:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct Foo
{
    int age_;
    std::string name_;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& rhs)
    {
        return os << rhs.age_ << " " << rhs.name_;
    }
    struct Compare // custom comparator
    {
        bool by_name_; // compare by age
        Compare(bool by_name = false): by_name_(by_name) {}
        bool operator()(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs)
        {
            return by_name_ ? (lhs.name_ < rhs.name_) : (lhs.age_ < rhs.age_);
        }
    };
};

int main()
{
    Foo x{1, "Silver"}, y{2, "John"}, z{3, "Long"};

    std::set<Foo, Foo::Compare> by_name(Foo::Compare{true}); // sort by name
    by_name.insert(x);
    by_name.insert(y);
    by_name.insert(z);

    std::set<Foo, Foo::Compare> by_age(Foo::Compare{false}); // sort by age
    by_age.insert(x);
    by_age.insert(y);
    by_age.insert(z);

    std::cout << "By name:" << std::endl;
    for (auto && elem : by_name)
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    std::cout << "By age:" << std::endl;
    for (auto && elem : by_age)
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7786ea7cb6f07d56)

Comment: Danger: changing sorting method after set is populated will possibly cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Yakk I don't get it... the `std::set` is copying the functor inside it, at construction. I don't use a `static` flag. Can you elaborate? Are you thinking about `std::sort`?

Comment: was not aimed at your code, but at the technique.  In the OP's case the controlling int was stored externally (which your technique could be adapted to by storing an `int*`), and that way lies madness.  Your answer solved a technical problem, but did not warn of the cliff adjacent.